# What are the steps I could follow to debug non-functioning JSS app integrated mode?

Tags: jss

My JSS app does not render in integrated mode: http://my-first-jss-app.dev.local/en-US/. The header renders (with logo, documentation styleguide links) but the content does not. What are the steps I could follow to debug the non-functioning JSS app integrated mode?

I am following the steps described to create a JSS app per instructions here: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/app-deployment.

The app renders ok in Experience Editor.

The environment is `Sitecore 9.0.2` standalone.

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       my-first-jss-app.dev.local
```

IIS Sitecore site sc9dev includes http binding my-first-jss-app.dev.local

The license shows correctly.

ShowConfig.aspx includes

```
<site name="my-first-jss-app" inherits="website" hostName="my-first-jss-app.dev.local" rootPath="/sitecore/content/my-first-jss-app" startItem="/home" database="master" patch:source="my-first-jss-app.config"/>
```

Any suggestions about what to look for are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause: the content wasn't available in the locale specified by URL: en-US.

The docs, https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/app-deployment, will create content in en. There will be an en.yml file in the [app]\data\routes folder.

To create content in en-US, refer to https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/content-translation.

1. Copy en.yml as en-US.yml
2. jss deploy items --language=en-US --includeContent --includeDictionary
   [image]